# получение свойства name элемента input в директиве angularJS

Tags: angularjs

Добрый день. коллеги есть проблема. пытаюсь получить значения поля в директиве из элементов input в каждом из которых прописана директива page и подставлять это значение в appData.dataSrc[ключ] в качестве ключа, но дело в том, что каждый раз подставляется одно и тоже значение. подскажите пожалуйста как решить проблему

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function () {
            "use strict";
            angular.module('app', [])

                 .service("appData", function () {
                    this.dataSrc = { field1:['zak'], field2:['bob'], field3:['nick'] };
                 })

                 .controller("someController", function ($scope, appData) {

                })

            .directive('page', function ($compile, appData) {
                return {
                    restrict: 'A',
                    scope: false,
                    require:'ngModel',
                    link: function (scope, element, attributes, ctrl) {
                        if (ctrl.$name == ctrl.$name) {
                            var content = $compile("<input type='button' value='{{say1()}}' ng-click=say();><span ng-show='isShow();'><ul><li  ng-repeat='item in getError()'>{{item}}</li><ul></span><span ng-bind='item'></span>")(scope);
                            element.after(content);
                       }

                        scope.getError = function () {
                            var key = ctrl.$name;
                            return appData.dataSrc[key];
                        }

                        scope.isShow = function () {
                            return true;
                        }

                        scope.say = function (value) {
                            alert("alloha friends" + " " + value);
                        };

                        scope.say1 = function () {
                            return "some text of the say 1";
                        };

                        scope.say2 = function () {
                            return "some text of the say 2";
                        };

                        scope.say3 = function () {
                            return "some text of the say 3";
                        };


                    },

                }
            })
        })();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="someController">
    <input type="text"
        ng-model="some1"
        name="field1"
        page
        />
    <br>
    <input type="text"
        ng-model="some2"
        name="field2"
        page
        />
    <br>
    <input type="text"
        ng-model="some3"
        name="field3"
        page
        />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _ctrl.$name == ctrl.$name_ - данное условие может не выполниться только если `ctrl.$name` - `NaN`

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что директивы не имеют своего скопа, поэтому каждая директива при инициализации переписывает функции которые были объявлены ранее.

Быстрофикс - использовать дочерний скоп, `scope:true`

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  angular.module('app', [])

  .service("appData", function() {
    this.dataSrc = {
      field1: ['zak'],
      field2: ['bob'],
      field3: ['nick']
    };
  })

  .controller("someController", function($scope, appData) {

  })

  .directive('page', function($compile, appData) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: true,
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attributes, ctrl) {
        var content = $compile("<input type='button' value='{{say1()}}' ng-click=say();><span ng-show='isShow();'><ul><li  ng-repeat='item in getError()'>{{item}}</li><ul></span><span ng-bind='item'></span>")(scope);
        element.after(content);

        scope.getError = function() {
          var key = ctrl.$name;
          return appData.dataSrc[key];
        }

        scope.isShow = function() {
          return true;
        }

        scope.say = function(value) {
          alert("alloha friends" + " " + value);
        };

        scope.say1 = function() {
          return "some text of the say 1";
        };

        scope.say2 = function() {
          return "some text of the say 2";
        };

        scope.say3 = function() {
          return "some text of the say 3";
        };


      },

    }
  })
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="someController">
  <input type="text" ng-model="some1" name="field1" page />
  <br>
  <input type="text" ng-model="some2" name="field2" page />
  <br>
  <input type="text" ng-model="some3" name="field3" page />
</div>
```

но лучше переработать саму директиву, например использовать контроллеры, использовать нормальные шаблоны вместо составления их с помощью сервиса $compile и т.д.